Definition File for a an AzDataFactoryV2LinkedService
I am writing some code to create some Azure ressource using the PowerShell CLI. Currently, I aim at setting up a LinkedService to pull some JSON data from a REST API.
When I run the code, the linked service gets created however the "Auth header" do not get set as seen in the Linked Service of the Data Factory, see image ADF screenshot.
Could you please advise about how to update the Definition File so that the Auth Header persist. Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.
The PowerShell Code is:
Set-AzDataFactoryV2LinkedService `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -DataFactoryName $dataFactoryName `
    -Name $SourceLinkedServiceName `
    -DefinitionFile $source_LS_path

The JSON definition file for this function is below:
{
  "name": "LS_Name",
  "type": "RestService",
  "properties": {
    "typeProperties": {
      "url": "url.com",
      "headers": {
        "accept": "path",
        "Arc-Version": "000-00-00",
        "authorization": "Bearer token"
      },
      "authenticationType": "Anonymous"
    }
  }
}

I would expect the Auth header to show up in the Linked Service as defined in the json file.

what is your CLI version here?

Hello, I am using the PowerShell CLI on the portal.azure.com website. The version details can be found below:
{
"azure-cli": "2.65.0",
"azure-cli-core": "2.65.0",
"azure-cli-telemetry": "1.1.0",
"extensions": {
"ai-examples": "0.2.5",
"ml": "2.30.1",
"ssh": "2.0.5"
}
}
Thanks

According to the MS document you should mention Authentication headers as below:
"authHeaders": { "x-api-key": { "type": "SecureString", "value": "<API key>" }

Here is sample Json file which is used to create Rest linked service:
{
    "properties": {
        "type": "RestService",
        "typeProperties": {
            "url": "https://url.com",
            "enableServerCertificateValidation": true,
            "authenticationType": "Anonymous",
            "authHeaders": {
                "x-api-key": {
                    "type": "SecureString",
                    "value": "<API key>"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Below is the PowerShell script to create Rest linked service:
Set-AzDataFactoryV2LinkedService -ResourceGroupName "<resourceGroupName>" -DataFactoryName "<ADFName>"  -Name "<linkedServiceName>" -DefinitionFile <jsonFileName> 

It run successfully as shown below:

Linked service is created but headers are not created in linked service as shown below:

Along with that if I created the linked service manually with headers, after refreshing the data factory studio headers are missing in linked service. It may be bug. check this bug request or raise support ticket.

Hello, thanks for this answer. I tried adding the "x-api-key" under the "authHeaders" in the Definition File but also ran into the same issue. I will keep an eye on the bug request. Thanks

Headers are created but have been encrypted so they cannot be listed in UI. As long as you have provided the right value, this linked service should work well (test connection, copy, etc.)

Hello. That makes sense as to why the "Headers" are encrypted. However, while the test connection does work, the preview of the source does not and I get a 404 error message when I try a copy action.

That must be a different problem? If Headers is not saved correctly, I believe you will hit 401 or 403.  If it is 404, maybe the path you specified doesn't exist?

I also try to query that API from a different platform and get a 404 error if I do not include the "Headers", and the expected result if I do.
The same thing happens when I use ADF, I get a  404 error when I use the CLI and the headers values do not show, and a the expected result if I edit the LinkedService manually and add the "Headers".
This makes me think it is the same problem
